# Docusign - Change Completed Signing Notification Emaill Message/Blurb

Tags: docusignapi

I imagine this is something simple and I'm just not looking in the right spot for it.

Is there a way to write a custom email blurb for the completed signing email notification the same way you can generate one for the request for signature notification within the embedded signing API code?

Currently my integration has the first signer embedded, then is emailed to two further recipients.  All the requests for signatures have the custom HTML I've created in our application as the "emailBlurb" in the XML request body but I don't see any options to set the message for the completed signing one as well.

Sorry if this is something easy in a FAQ or guide somewhere and I just missed it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A majority of the Email notifications that DocuSign sends can be customized via modification of the "Email Resource File" (an XML file that contains text strings used in the emails that DocuSign sends).  You can access Resource Files via the DocuSign web console (when logged in as an Administrator) by going to Preferences >> Branding >> [Edit Brand] (link) >> Resources (tab).

This [guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-system-default-email-formats) provides all the information you should need to customize the Resource File:

Note that an Email Resource file applies to a specific "Brand" -- i.e.,all envelopes that use a specific Brand will derive their content from the Email Resource file that's associated with that Brand. It's not currently possible to specify email contents (other than the **EmailBlurb** in the signing invitation email) via the API. But, depending on the nature of your email customization requirements, you could always create multiple Brands via the DocuSign web console, customize the Email Resource file differently for each Brand, and then set **BrandId** in each "Create Envelope" API call to affiliate the correct Brand (and therefore email contents) with each envelope.

Comment: Thank you Kim.  This looks to be exactly what I was looking for.