# customize email template for docusign api

Tags: docusignapi, email-templates, branding

We want to apply our dynamic content/text on notification email send by docusign to signers. DocuSign sends many different notification email to signers about envelope create, send, declined, completed and etc. We want to customize those default templates of docusign through the **REST API**. In these customized email templates, **we will have our own merge fields which can be replaced with our user's data**. Is there any **API method** or options available so we can achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818614/docusign-change-completed-signing-notification-emaill-message-blurb?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) Api call, you can specify customized emailSubject and emailBlurb at envelope & recipient level

In the following example,

- "*recipient one*" will receive an email with subject "*This is recipient one subject*".
- "*recipient two*"  will receive an email with subject "*Email Subject to all recipients*"

JSON

```
 {
   "emailSubject": "Email Subject to all recipients",
   "emailBlurb": "Email body to all recipients",
   "recipients": {
     "signers": [
       {
         "recipientId": 1,
         "email": "recipient1@foobar.com",
         "name": "recipient one",
         "emailNotification": {
           "emailSubject": "This is recipient one subject",
           "emailBody": "This is recipient one email body"
         }
       },
       {
         "recipientId": 2,
         "email": "recipient2@foobar.com",
         "name": "recipient two"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

---

**Creating from Templates**

You can also insert recipient name and email address merge fields into the email subject line when creating or sending from a template. [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#template-email-subject-merge-fields)

---

**Email Resource File**

This is not a Rest Api operation, but you can also configure custom resource files for emails in your account configuration using the Docusign Web Console. 
YOu can then specify the Brand Id in your createEnvelope Rest Api call
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818614/docusign-change-completed-signing-notification-emaill-message-blurb?rq=1)

Comment: @CoudingDwan.. Hi emailBlurb that we are already using. But my question is about to apply own merged filed on email template resource. Suppose In envelope declined email/template some where we want to add merge filed like [[MyFieldData] and value of this 'MyFieldData', we will set while creating envelope. And this value will be automatically applied in declined email notification message as per template when some one declined the envelope. is that can be possible.