# DocuSign Email Resource File - Changing Default email for RecipientEnvelopeComplete

Tags: docusignapi

Email is showing original Text from Template message.  I removed:

```
[[Conditional:CCRecipientNote]]<div style="font-size:15px;color:#333333;padding:20px;border-radius:2px;border:1px solid #dddddd;margin-bottom:20px;"> [[Conditional:CCRecipientNote]]    <div style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#666666;padding-bottom:20px;">PRIVATE MESSAGE</div> [[Conditional:CCRecipientNote]][[Data:CCRecipientNote]]</div>

[[Conditional:EmailBlurb]]<p style="font-size:15px;color:#333333;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans Serif;line-height:20px;">[[Data:EmailBlurb]]</p>
[[Conditional:Information]]<p style="font-size:15px;color:#333333;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans Serif;line-height:20px;">[[Data:Information]]</p>
```

To remove the original message.  I uploaded Email resource and see the modified template.  I test and nothing has changed.  I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you creating a new brand? If so, you have to set the BrandId in your CreateEnvelope call. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19819269/1219543)

Comment: No.  I modified the default DocuSign Send brand.

Comment: Have you checked if the language that you are receiving the emails is the same language you upload your file to? We were having similar problems with pt_br and pt.